# Organise & Name Uploaded Files

Tags: php, file-upload

What's the best way to ogranise and name uploaded files?

I maybe wrong on this, but I feel it's not good practice to save all files in one directory, as this will result in slowness of the filesystem if the file ever needed to be browsed?

All thoughts and idea's welcome

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i use a function like this to generate a 3-level folder's tree for uploaded files:

```
function get_1000_path($id)
{
  $id = strval($id);
  $id = str_repeat("0", 9 - strlen($id)).$id;

  $path = substr($id, 0, 3)."/".substr($id, 3, 3)."/".substr($id, 6, 3)."/";

  return $path;
}
```

so max count of files in one subfolder is 1000, filesystem will work well

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your application is working.

If it's something like users galleries, I would simply create one folder for every user, then a year -> month structure.

If files are commonly shared by all the users, I would organize them in different directories based on time (year -> month -> week -> day). If your site is not expecting a lot of traffic, a year -> month division should be enough.

I would use [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function to rename the uploaded files so that there will be no need to check for overwrite or duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your system/site or needs, ie. for a user portal it could be better like this `user_images/USER-ID/filename-unid_id.jpg`. For example, this could be usefull `uploads/news_images/YYYY/MM/DD/filename-unid_id.jpg` type for a news site. At this point it won't need large unid_id's like md5 or something else and you can use php `hash` like: `$unid_id = hash('crc32b', microtime())`. Cos there are hard line collution possibilities.

```
// in your upload file
$dir = "uploads/news_images/". date("Y-m-d");
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    if (!is_writable($dir)) chmod($dir, 0777); // try again changing mod
}
```

But, both two example, you need to store file name/path of each file. In this way, you use this method to store data (personally I use json format when storing many data togather and if I don't need to search on);

```
// table "news_images"
id | file_name | file_data
--------------------------
1  | blue fish | {"path":"2012/12/12", "slug":"blue-fish-9834a12b", "ext":"jpg" ...
```

Good lucks..